# text/html copy to clipboard without any style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clipboard

i use from this code for copy to clipboard **htmlLink** :

```
    htmlLink = "<a href='#'>link</a>";
    var copyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    copyDiv.contentEditable = true;
    document.body.appendChild(copyDiv);
    copyDiv.innerHTML = htmlLink;
    copyDiv.unselectable = "off";
    copyDiv.focus();
    document.execCommand('SelectAll');
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
    document.body.removeChild(copyDiv);
```

but after paste in tinyMCE text editor there are some styles in that.

paste return:

```
<a style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #1bc5bd; text-decoration-line: none; background-color: #f3f6f9; transition: color 0.15s ease 0s, background-color 0.15s ease 0s, border-color 0.15s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease 0s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease 0s; font-family: iransans, tahoma; font-size: 13px; outline: 0px !important;" href="#">link</a>
```

These styles come from public website css classes that i dont want,

How do I remove these styles?

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is to append it to a place that is far from influenced by styles. But where?

Comment: Notice: I know that this can be done by changing the div element to textarea, but after that it is no longer pasted as a html in text editor such as tinyMCE .

Answer (score 2):

I change my code to this and problex fixed.

```
    htmlLink = "<a href='#'>link</a>";
    function listener(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", htmlLink );
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", htmlLink );
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
```